# Show a SplitViewController, when user press a button?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

i'ts possible call/load a SplitViewController, when user press a button ???

for example, in my app i have a button called "Settings". When the user press that button, i'd like show the SplitViewController...

somebody help me ??

```
 PD. Already did a easy example with SplitViewController:
 but i don't know a solution for my problem..
```

Answer (score 1):

`UISplitViewController` is inherited from the UIViewController. You can just push it onto navigation stack or perform seque if you use storyboards. If you use nibs then first instantiate it with initWithNibNamed: and then `[self.navigationController pushViewController: yourSplitViewController]`.